# Contribute CS5 Connection to Apache2 Server SFTP issues

Tags: apache-2.2, sftp, adobe

We moved a few websites to an Apache2 setup and have since not been able to connect to the server with SFTP. I get a password / username error. There is no load on the server. SSH is configured. Permissions are correct. I can access it via WinSCP, Dreamweaver and Putty, but not Contribute. Anyone have any clues here?

Here is some more server info:

```
Apache2
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (i586)
VERSION = 10
PATCHLEVEL = 3
/etc/SuSE-release
```

**apache2ctl -V**

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Apr 14 2010 11:41:47
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:3
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.2, APR-Util 1.2.2
Compiled using: APR 1.2.2, APR-Util 1.2.2
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....

 - -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"  -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE  -D
   APR_HAS_MMAP  -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)  -D
   APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE  -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE  -D
   SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT  -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD  -D
   AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS  -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128  -D
   HTTPD_ROOT="/srv/www"  -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec2"  -D
   DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/httpd2.pid"  -D
   DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"  -D
   DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/accept.lock"  -D
   DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="/var/log/apache2/error_log"  -D
   AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/mime.types"  -D
   SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does contribute cache "known hosts" values? Perhaps it's failing expecting a different ssh key for the site.

Comment: I don't think so. I've deleted all the server files associated with Contribute and still get the issue....